# How to prove $\mathbb{E}[\left | \frac{1}{n} \sum X_i-\mu \right |]=\mathcal{O}(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}})$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$?

Tags: central-limit-theorem

$X_i$ is iid sequence with mean $\mu$ and finite variance $\sigma^2$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: because $E[Y^2] \ge (E[Y])^2$ (Jensen’s)

Answer (score 1):

To prove it, you don't need central limit theorem. By a special case of [Holder's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C3%B6lder%27s_inequality), we have
\begin{equation}
E[|\bar{X} - \mu|] \leq \sqrt{E[(\bar{X} - \mu)^2]} = \sqrt{\mathrm{Var}(\bar{X})} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\sigma = O(1/\sqrt{n}).
\end{equation}